# How to continuously monitor a group of threads then perform some action after they have ended?

Tags: c#

How can I continuously monitor a group of threads then perform some action after they have ended.

My code is as follows:

```
int threadcount = 5;

for (int i = 0; i < threadcount; i++)
{                    
  _azgetThread = new Thread(() => Getazuredata());
  _azgetThread.Start();
}
```

In the above case 5 threads(_azgetThread ) are created and I would like to monitor them and know when they have ended.

I am familiar with _azgetThread.IsAlive but in this case there are multiple instances.

Comment: What do you mean by monitor? Do you just mean know when they are done?

Comment: I mean know when they are done

Comment: Thread.Join will do that.  But that blocks the thread "Waiting".  If you have more specific details, please include them.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of running the five operations in parallel within one thread rather than creating 5 threads? I suggest this since you are simply waiting for them to finish.

Comment: Do you have any info on how to run 5 operations in one thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good option here is to use a [CountdownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.aspx).  Each thread can set the event when it's completed, and the main thread can just check to see if the event is set or call [Wait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270870.aspx) on it.

You can always use your same mechanism (checking `IsAlive`), but you would need to store your threads in an array or `List<Thread>` instead of using a single variable for all 5 threads.

That being said, I'd also recommend using the TPL instead of individual threads.  Depending on your work, you could use `Parallel.For` or `Parallel.ForEach` to run all 5 items, or even use PLINQ across a collection of items.  If you want to keep the same logic, you could use `Task.Factory.StartNew` and [`Task.WhenAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall.aspx) to schedule a Task that will notify you when the 5 initial tasks have completed.

Comment: Deleted my answer when I realised how much it overlapped with this one; instead I'll just mention this in a comment: You can also use Parallel.Invoke(), e.g. `Parallel.Invoke(action1, action2, action3, action4, action5);`